# Lift UIView above view

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, hierarchy, subview

I have one interesting problem.

I have view (UIView) A with subview A.1, A.2,... Above that I have another view (UIView) B.
I need it to be B above A (because some view from A dissapear beneath view B).

What I need is to be only one subview from view A (for example A.1) above view B.

Is there a way to lift subview above another view so that all other view stays beneath?

Comment: What you're asking for is not possible. A.1 shouldn't be a subview of A if it needs to appear above B, where B is above A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't do that... if you bringSubviewToFront A then its all subviews are showing above on B.

In that case you have to hidden subview which you dont want to see.

You can use below methods to for showing A on top.

```
[A.superview bringSubviewToFront:A];
```

Or you can put B below A with this method.

```
[B.superview sendSubviewToBack:B];
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can do it using those two functions:

```
[self bringSubviewToFront:view];
[self sendSubviewToBack:view];
```

In manipulates Z-index of your view.

Comment: He's asking for a subview of A (A.1) to appear above B, where B is above A. Your code will only bring A.1 above A.2.